# Customize the Sidebar (Pages) in Streamlit to Have Sections

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am working on a simple multipage Streamlit app that allows CRUD operations to be performed on some data. I understand that creating a `pages` directory will allows me to have multiple pages in my app, which is what I have done as shown here,

[image]

My project structure looks like this,

```
/Home.py
/pages/Add_Pikcups.py
/pages/View_Pickups.py
```

Now, I want to have multiple sections  in my app. For instance, these are the pages that come under the 'Pickups' section and then I would also like to have a 'Drops' section as so on.

Is there some way I can customize my sidebar to display the pages as these multiple sections?

So, I'd want something like,

Pickups

- Add Pickups
- View Pickups

Drops

- Add Drops
- View Drops

Not as bullet points, but I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
pages/drops.py

import streamlit as st


st.sidebar.radio('drops sub-menu', options=['add drops', 'view drops'])
st.sidebar.checkbox('special')
```

```
pages/pickups.py

import streamlit as st


st.sidebar.selectbox('Person incharge', options=['john', 'peter'], index=0)
st.sidebar.selectbox('location', options=['manila', 'tokyo'], index=1)
```

#### Drops output

[image]

#### Pickups output

[image]

Comment: This is great, but for example, when I click on `add drops`, I should be redirected to a new page. How do I do that?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/4832#issuecomment-1201938174